# The sum $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + \dots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. What is the value of $21^2 + 22^2 + \dots + 40^2$?

Tags: summation, induction

The sum $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + \cdots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. What is the value of $21^2 + 22^2 + \cdots + 40^2$? Using induction, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use your formula for $n=40$ and for $n=20$. Subtract the two results: $21^2+...+40^2=(1^2+...+40^2)-(1^2+...+20^2)$.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

We can consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^{40} n^2-\sum_{n=1}^{20} n^2$$

Answer (score 3):

By your formula:
$$1^2+2^2+\dots+40^2 - (1^2+\dots+20^2) = \frac{40\cdot 41 \cdot 81-20\cdot21\cdot 41}{6}.$$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need induction.  The sum from $21$ to $40$ is the sum from $1$ to $40$ less ???

Answer (score 2):

You've stated that:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{n}{x^2}=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

$$\sum_{x=21}^{40}{x^2}=\sum_{x=1}^{40}{x^2}-\sum_{x=1}^{20}{x^2}$$
Simply use the formula to evaluate this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need induction to calculate that value.
Value is simply $$(1^2+2^2+...40^2)-(1^2+2^2+...20^2)$$